pasar de un campo al otro en campos creados dinamicamente
Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar con esto...
les cuento que tengo un formulario de esos que se agregan campos dinamicos.. el cual en el campo padre no hay problema
  <label>Hora Inicio: </label>
                   <input name="hora1_operario[]" type="text" class="hora1" autocomplete="off" id="hora1_operario" size="1" maxlength="5" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) hora2_operario.focus()"/>
                   <label>Hora Final:
                     <input name="hora2_operario[]" type="text" class="hora2" autocomplete="off" id="hora2_operario" size="1"/>
</label>

ya que esta linea lo que hace es que al escribir mas de 5 caracteres en el campo se pasa automaticamente al otro..
 maxlength="5" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) hora2_operario.focus()"

pero hay un problema y es en el juego de campos que se crean como un wraper al agregar campos no se como ponerle la misma opcion ya que como es por ID del campo no puedo ponerle la misma id a estos
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField2 = 10; //
    var addButton2 = $('.add_button2'); //agrega
    var wrapper2 = $('.field_wrapper2'); //wrapper  
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton2).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField2){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper2).append(fieldHTML2); // Add field html
             $('.selector').select2();
             console.log(x);
        }
    });
    $(wrapper2).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
        console.log(x);
    });
    
});

<!----------------------------PARTE (AQUI)---------------------------------------------------->
 var fieldHTML2 = '<div id="destino2"><label>Operador: </label><select name="operario[]" style="width:500px" required class="campos selector"><option value="">Seleccione:</option><?php if (($_SESSION['tipo']=="admin")||($quien=="Facturacion")||($quien=="Operativo")){$query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT nombre AS trabajador, municipio AS municp FROM datos_archivo WHERE estadotrabajador='ACTIVO' AND cargo IN ('OPERARIO LIMPIEZA','OPERADOR DE BARRIDO/ESCOBITA','OPERADOR SANEAMIENTO BASICO','SUPERVISOR DE RUTAS','OPERADOR SANEAMIENTO BASICO Y BARRIDO') ORDER BY nombre ASC");}else{$query2 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT nombre AS trabajador, municipio AS municp FROM datos_archivo WHERE estadotrabajador='ACTIVO' AND cargo IN ('OPERARIO LIMPIEZA','OPERADOR DE BARRIDO/ESCOBITA','OPERADOR SANEAMIENTO BASICO','SUPERVISOR DE RUTAS','OPERADOR SANEAMIENTO BASICO Y BARRIDO') AND municipio='$municcc' ORDER BY nombre ASC");}$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");while ($valores2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { echo '<option value="'.strtoupper($valores2[trabajador]).'">'.strtoupper($valores2[trabajador]).' - '.strtoupper($valores2['municp']).'</option>';}?></select> <?php /*?><label>Apoyo: </label><select name="apoyo[]" id="apoyo" class="campos"><option value="">No</option><option value="Operador de Apoyo a la Recoleccion">Apoyo</option><option value="Operador Foraneo">Foraneo</option>  </select><?php */?> <label>Hora Inicio: </label><input name="hora1_operario[]" type="text" class="hora1" id="hora"+x+"_operario" autocomplete="off" size="1"/><label> Hora Final: <input name="hora2_operario[]" type="text" class="hora2" autocomplete="off" size="1" /></label> <?php /*?>H.E: <input name="he[]" type="checkbox" value="si"/></label><?php */?> Novedad de Operario: <textarea name="novedad_operario[]" cols="30" id="novedadoperario"></textarea> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Borrar Operario de Saneamiento"><img src="remove-icon.png" width="20" height="20"/></a></div>'; //New input field html
  </script>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

es en esta parte del extenso código anterior, como ven puse un console.log  que me muestra el numero consecutivo al agregar o eliminar el juego de campos, e intente ponerle una ID dinámica a el campo id="hora"+x+"_operario" para si ir jugando pero NO me sirvió.. pienso que en la opción seria mejor en vez de poner el nombre de la ID del campo a saltar poner que sea mejor un TAB y así saltaría al campo siguiente...
<label>Hora Inicio: </label><input name="hora1_operario[]" type="text" class="hora1" id="hora"+x+"_operario" autocomplete="off" size="1"/><label> Hora Final: <input name="hora2_operario[]" type="text" class="hora2" autocomplete="off" size="1" />

estoy intentandolo hacer mediante una funcion pero no me da para usarlo usando clases
<script>
function saltar() {
if(uno.value.length==6){
dos.focus();
}
}
</script>
<input type="text" class="unoo" id="uno" onKeyUp="saltar()">
<input type="text" class="doss" id="dos">

por que me sirve asi (usando ID)
<script>
function saltar() {
       var elm = document.getElementById("uno");
      //var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("unoo");
if(elm.value.length==6){
dos.focus();
}
}
</script>
<input type="text" class="unoo" id="uno" onKeyUp="saltar()">
<input type="text" class="doss" id="dos">

y no asi
<script>
function saltar() {
       //var elm = document.getElementById("uno");
         var elm = document.getElementsByClassName("unoo");
if(elm.value.length==6){
dos.focus();
}
}
</script>
<input type="text" class="unoo" id="uno" onKeyUp="saltar()">
<input type="text" class="doss" id="dos">


Para lograr lo que quieres te sugiero que aprendas a usar una técnica en Javascript que se llama Event Delegation.
Básicamente, en vez de agregar múltiples handlers del evento keyup a cada input, se lo agregas a un elemento padre que todos los inputs tengan en común, cuando alguno de los inputs dentro del elemento padre emita el evento keyup, podrás capturarlo y agregar la lógica para determinar cuando hacer focus al siguiente input. Aquí tienes un ejemplo sencillo:


#container input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Agregar un Input</button>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Comienza a escribir!</h1>
</div>

<script>      
  // esta función agrega un input genérico el cual recibe un maxlength
  function addNewInput(max) {
    var template = '<input maxlength="'+max+'" type="text" />';
    $('#container').append(template);
  }
  
  // agrega un nuevo input dinamicamente al dar click al boton:
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var randomMaxLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 3;
    addNewInput(randomMaxLength);
  });

  // aquí simplemente agrego algunos inputs iniciales a modo de prueba
  addNewInput(5);
  addNewInput(10);
  $('input:first').focus();

  // solución: delega el evento keyup en un elemento padre
  // en vez de agregarlo en cada input:
  $('#container').on('keyup', 'input', function(e) {
    // captura el input que recibió el evento
    var $input = $(e.target);
    var length = $input.val().length;
    var max = +$input.attr('maxlength');

    // revisa si el input esta lleno
    if (length === max) {
      // haz focus al siguiente input
      $(e.target).next('input').focus();
    }
  });
</script>




que maravilla...!! mil gracias por responder pero como lo aplico a mi script..
